# How to get the url from a string

Tags: postgresql-9.1

** Hi , I have string like below.

```
 '{"","",https://www.facebook.com/bluecsushi/photos/pb.10007642612.-2207520000.1403730752./10151966146267613/?type=3,1780830_10151966146267613_759424320_n.jpg}'
```

and i want get the result: www.facebook.com can u some one tell me

Answer (score 0):

Using [substring](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) function and regular expression:

```
substring('https://www.facebook.com/bluecsushi/photos/' from 'www.*.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)')
```

this will return:

```
www.facebook.com
```